# OBS video becomes choppy after I change monitor

Tags: video, graphics-card, resolution, obs-studio

I used to have Xiaomi Ultra Short Throw Projector.

I recorded the game and the result is like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GbqRv_BJiA

I then change my monitor to Wemax Xiaomi Ultra Short Throw Projector

I recorded the game and the result is like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkoWW8N0VZg

Notice the videos are very choppy.

The new projector is 4k monitor. I change the monitor resolution and the game to full had. The result is that the video is still choppy

I wonder why

The projector is capable of receiving 4k monitor and the native resolution is 4k. However, I set the resolution lower hoping that the choppiness is gone. It's not.

What is actually going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue

My first reaction is to use less encoding.

Basically don't compress the video too much.

It turns out when I do that, another killer option shows up.

Uses hardware encoding.

Yayyyy

Now my video is much more clear and the videos are not choppy at all. Yes the hard disk used is much larger.

So what?
[image]